# Prove that consecutive integers are always coprime

Tags: proof-verification

I'm wondering if the proof below is strong enough to prove that consecutive integers are always coprime.

Let $a$ and $(a+1)$ be our $2$ numbers, and suppose $a$ has $k$ that divides it, then we have $a\equiv 0 \bmod(k)$ , and adding $1$ to each side gives us $a+1\equiv 1\bmod(k)$.  And since we can do this to every divisor of $a$ they can never share the same divisor.

Comment: That shows that no divisor of $a$ is a divisor of $a+1$.  But how do you show that no divisor of $a+1$ is a divisor of $a$?

Comment: Hit: A common divisor of $a$ and $b$ also divides $b-a$

Comment: @fleablood ah yes, I forgot that

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hagen von Eitzen's comment:

Let $k (\not =1)$ be a common divisor of $a+1$ and $a$.

Then

$k$ divides $(a+1)-a$ (why?).

Since $(a+1)-a =1$,  $k$ divides $1$, a contradiction.

P.S. A similar argument can be used to prove that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: For the why part apply $k\mid b\iff kc=b$ for some integer $c$. E.g $kr=a$ and $ks=a+1$ so that $ (a+1)-a=(s-r)k=tk$ which implies $k\mid 1$.

Comment: Pixel.Yes. Try to argue that there are infinitely many primes using a similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can elaborate your answer more properly using $\text{ 'Fundamental Theorem Of Arithmetic' }$.

Let The prime factorization of a number $A$ be :
$$ A = p_0^{a_0}.p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}.....p_n^{a_n}$$

Then  $A+1$ would be :
$$ A+1 = p_0^{a_0}.p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}.....p_n^{a_n} + 1$$

Since when divided by any $ p \space \space (p|A)$ , it will always leave the remainder $1$ , we can conclude that $A $ and  $A+1$ are always co-prime.